# Solvent for caffeine extraction

Tags: solvents

Can anybody please help me find a way to separate caffeine from coffee that uses a solvent other than DCM, ethyl acetate, or diethyl ether?

This an experiment for science class, but I don't have access to any of the above-mentioned solvents.

Can you suggest any alternatives that are easily obtainable?

Comment: Supercritical $CO_2$?

Comment: It is kind of silly for us to guess 50 solvents to try and find one that you can use. I suggest you use Google ["Extraction of Caffeine"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&ei=ZLSrXOiNJsmEsAWb16Eg&q=%22Extraction+of+Caffeine%22&oq=%22Extraction+of+Caffeine%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67l2j0l3j0i7i30l2j0i67j0l2.3184.7785..9735...0.0..0.135.498.0j4......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.d9Ht_RAnd7I) and find a suitable solvent yourself. // I know that you are not going to have the equipment to use supercritical carbon dioxide.

Comment: Can you use Acetone?

Comment: @Waylander thanks for the reply but i don't think it would work all for the fact that acetone is miscable in water this is the same reason i can't use ethanol aswel if it weren't miscable it would work. Thanks for taking the time to reply!                                                 I apreciate it.

Comment: It would be better to re-word your question by stating the names of solvents which are available to you.

Comment: Here are three NileRed videos, you may find some helpful solvent information in them, or at least enjoy them with a nice cup of coffee or tea ;-) 1) [How to extract Caffeine from Coffee](https://youtu.be/_CoxEgbyeK4) 2) [How to extract Caffeine from Tea (Classic DCM Method)](https://youtu.be/RIbff5iD0GQ) 3) [How to extract Caffeine from Caffeine Pills](https://youtu.be/ZdTc1AFTKZ0) Also enjoyable are Periodic Videos [How much caffeine in coffee?](https://youtu.be/Xzh-6ZDitQ8) and [Tea Chemistry - Periodic Table of Videos](https://youtu.be/EFPosXIYGP0)

Comment: Your question isn't bad. The wording has been improved, but people who leave "drive-by downvotes" probably won't return to notice and change them, so I"m voting `+1` since your question as currently written seems reasonable enough to at least be non-negative!

Answer (score 1):

Following is the list of solvents previously checked for the solubility (From reference 1 below):

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textrm{Solvent} & \textrm{Temperature, } \pu{^{\circ}C}  & \textrm{Solubility, } \pu{\%} (w/w) \\ \hline
 \textrm{Water} & 25 & 2.2  \\ \hline
 \textrm{water} & 100  & 66.7  \\ \hline
 \textrm{Ethanol} & 25 & 1.2 \\ \hline
\textrm{ Ethanol} & 60 & 4.5 \\ \hline
\textrm{Ether} & 25 & 0.3 \\ \hline
\textrm{Ethyl Acetete} & 25 & 2.5 \\ \hline
\textrm{Chloroform} & 25 & 18.0 \\ \hline
\textrm{Acetone} & 25 & 2.0 \\ \hline
\textrm{Benzene} & 25 & 1.0 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

My suggestion is to use ethanol in $\pu{60 ^{\circ}C}$. However, I'm not sure how ethanol would behave with the presence of tannins. For example, in a separate literature report, $\pu{1.0 mg}$ of tannin was isolated from a $\pu{g}$ of grape skins using 100% ethanol while the amount was increased to about $\pu{5.5 mg}$ when solvent was switched to 100% acetone (Ref.2).

**References:**

1. Q. V. Vuong, P. D. Roach, “Caffeine in Green Tea: Its Removal and Isolation,” *Separation & Purification Reviews* **2014**, *43(2)*, 155-174 (DOI: 10.1080/15422119.2013.771127).
2. M. O. Downey, R. L. Hanlin, “Comparison of Ethanol and Acetone Mixtures for Extraction of Condensed Tannin from Grape Skin,” *South African Journal for Enology and Viticulture* **2010**, *31(2)*, 154–159 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.21548/31-2-1412).